# Why solidity doesn't use " Null " and "undefined"?

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.5.x, solidity-0.6.x

Like Python or any other language why does Solidity avoid having the Null and undefined properties?

Comment: What for?..........

Comment: @goodvibration just want to learn logic behind not using Null and undefined!!

Comment: Just asked what you were hoping to use it for, so I could suggest alternatives. `undefined` doesn't exist in any other language that I'm aware of, with the exception of Javascript (and Python if you consider `None` equivalent). So you could just as well as that about C, C++, Java, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variable cannot be set as `null` or undefined because the EVM does not have a concept of `null`. When a variable is declared, it initially contains the zero-equivalent of it's given type.

From the Solidity documentation on [types](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.10/types.html#types):

> The concept of “undefined” or “null” values does not exist in Solidity, but newly declared variables always have a default value dependent on its type.

And on [declarations](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.10/control-structures.html#scoping-and-declarations):

> A variable which is declared will have an initial default value whose byte-representation is all zeros. The “default values” of variables are the typical “zero-state” of whatever the type is. For example, the default value for a bool is false. The default value for the uint or int types is 0. For statically-sized arrays and bytes1 to bytes32, each individual element will be initialized to the default value corresponding to its type. For dynamically-sized arrays, bytes and string, the default value is an empty array or string. For the enum type, the default value is its first member.

Comment: I want to know why we don't use NULL and UNDEFINED?

Comment: @HaseebSaeed: You don't use them, because the language doesn't define them. The language doesn't define them, because just like many other languages, it does not consider them a necessary requirement. For example, C does not define them either. C++ and Java define `null`, but they do not define `undefined`. And there are many similar examples. So the question seems rather pointless. In contrast, you could ask what is the Solidity equivalent for these two concepts. But you'll need to show an example where they are actually needed.

Comment: @goodvibration thanks for your answer btw. I thought it could be an good idea to know the theoretical side of this issue.

Comment: @HaseebSaeed: If I were to speculate, then the theory behind this is that the authors of the language did not see any practical use of these concepts. That's why I said you should show a use-case (or a potential use-case) for them, so that readers of your question will be able to refer to it.